# How to multiply each Int value in an array by a constant in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Say, I have an array `[20, 2, 3]`
How can I multiply each Int value of this array in Swift?
So 2 x array becomes `[40, 4, 6]`, 3 x array becomes `[60, 6, 9]` and so on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `.map()`:

```
let values = [20, 2, 3]
let doubles = values.map { $0 * 2 }
let triples = values.map { $0 * 3 }
```

If you want to do the update in-place:

```
var values = [20, 2, 3]

values.enumerated().forEach { index, value in
  values[index] = value * 2
}
// values is now [40, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop.

```
    var array = [20, 2, 3]
    let multiplier = 2

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        array[i] = array[i] * multiplier
    }
```