# How can I raise all the elements in an int array by a power of 3 in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

For example say I have the array:

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would like to output a new array with the cube values: `[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]`

Do I have to use a loop?

Comment: `nums.map { $0 * $0 * $0 }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply each Int value in an array by a constant in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236312/how-to-multiply-each-int-value-in-an-array-by-a-constant-in-swift) and [Exponentiation operator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065801/exponentiation-operator-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**map()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) and [**pow()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1779833-pow) together:

```
import Foundation

let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let cubes = nums.map { Int(pow(Double($0), 3)) }
let raisedBySix = nums.map { Int(pow(Double($0), 6)) }
print(cubes)       // [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
print(raisedBySix) // [1, 64, 729, 4096, 15625, 46656]
```